# Process attachment after upload with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, paperclip

I'am using gems:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'mongoid','~>4.0.2'
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"
gem 'mongoid-paperclip'
```

I need process (parse some csv) when is file uploaded.

My code:

```
class MyModel
  #... mongoid and paperclip configuration
  after_save :parse_csv

  def parse_csv
    puts self.spreadsheet.path #works - path is correct
    puts self.spreadsheet.url #works - url is correct
    File.open self.spreadsheet.path #No such file or directory
end
```

How I can process files with after_save (or create) with Paperclip and Mongoid? In my callback, file still isn't saved on the file system.

Comment: Path is correct, I'll update it to question.

Comment: No, paperclip path is absolut and correct, there isn't problem

Answer (score 0):

```
def parse_csv
    puts self.spreadsheet.path
    puts self.spreadsheet.url
    File.open(Rails.root.join(self.spreadsheet.path))
end
```

This may solve your issue?